# Labyrinth/maze game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, collision-detection

I'm creating a very simple game in Flash AS3 including labyrinth. Here's the code:

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

oseba.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, premik);
oseba.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

var keys:Array = [];

function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}
function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}

function premik(e:Event):void{  
    if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT])       {
            oseba.x += 5;
        } 
    if (keys[Keyboard.LEFT])    {
        oseba.x -= 5;
    }
    if (keys[Keyboard.UP])  {
        oseba.y -= 5;
    }
    if (keys[Keyboard.DOWN])    {
        oseba.y += 5;
    }
}


function handleCollision(e:Event ):void{
    if(oseba.hitTestObject(nazaj)){
         gotoAndPlay(2,"igra");
    }
    if(oseba.hitTestObject(gozd)){
         gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

I'd like to add collision detection, that will disallow my ''`oseba`'' that is walking around from walking over unmarked terrain. Below I've created a non visible MC ''`potke`''. I supposed the best way would be to calculate ''`oseba`'' 's next position and if it's on ''`potke`'' then ''`oseba`'' can't move there. I'm looking for suitable example of code, cos I've tried few different already, but non seems to work.

I'm also receiving the following error: 
**TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at XYgame_fla::MainTimeline/handleCollision()**

Everything seems to work fine otherwise, but this error keeps showing up.

Comment: null object is either `nazaj` or `gozd`, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using nazaj.hitTestPoint(oseba.x, oseba,y, true) and put the EventListener to the stage to fix the error.